# Is there a way to rename parameters when including/reusing a module type in Coq?

Tags: coq, definition, module

Say I have a (more general) module type `Collection` that specifies some operations like read and write and now I want to create (more specialized) module types like `Stack` & `Queue`.

`Stack` for example, should have all operations that `Collection` has, so we want to save time by including `Collection` in `Stack`. However, with stacks, the "write" operation is typically called "push". What is the best way for `Stack` to reuse `Collection` while being able to do this renaming?

In the example below, any opaque usage of `Stack` will only expose `wr` but not the name `push`, as in `ListStack`

```
Module Type TypElt.
  Parameter t elt : Type.
End TypElt.

Module Type Collection (Import T: TypElt).

  (* Parameter rd : t -> (option elt * t). *)
  Parameter wr : elt -> t -> t.

End Collection.


Module Type Elt .
  Parameter elt : Type.
End Elt.

Module Type Stack (E: Elt).

  Definition elt := E.elt.
  Parameter t : Type.
  Include Collection.

  (* Notation pop := rd. *)
  Notation push := wr. (* <- doesn't achieve what I want *)
  (* Parameter peek : t -> option elt. *)
End Stack.

Module ListStack (E: Elt) <: Stack E.
  
  Definition elt := E.elt.
  Definition t := list elt.
  
  Definition push := @cons elt.

  (* In order to satisfy the Module Type Stack, we must provide an operation, wr *)

  Definition wr := push.

End ListStack.
```

Comment: I find your question quite confused/confusing: besides that the example doesn't match the question (you should at least edit that and make it more to the point): you can "reuse" a module, not a module type...  That said and fixed, the simple answer here might end up just being: do not `Include`, rather `Import` and wrap around it... no?

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio I'm... not sure which part doesn't match?

Nor do I understand you point about module type reuse. That Include works for module types would be evidence for their reuse no?

No... I don't see that Importing would give me the behaviour I want, which is to rename a parameter

Comment: Importing for *wrapping*: and you cannot import a module type.  I am a bit perplexed about the example code as e.g. I don't understand why you have a `ListStack` there, but especially I don't understand why `Elt` vs a totally unrelated `TypElt` for what looks like the Key/Value types.  Anyway, the point is the only approach for renaming that I can think of is by wrapping around the original module (and that per se cannot be a module type): I am not terribly an expert with Coq, but considering also that nobody else is chiming in, I might just put together an answer along those lines.

Comment: Indeed, the thing that confuses me most is how you expect to go from (apparently) a keyed collection to a stack, where pop and push only apply to the top-most element, by... just *renaming*?  I mean, to use that code, even just to answer the present question, I'd have to completely ignore what the naming suggests.

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio: Ah I see. I've used your feedback to hopefully make the question clearer. However, I think you are confused by some of the Coq-isms going on here. TypElt has a type of elements, and collections. `t` is meant to be abstract type of the collection (This is pretty typical in the stdlib which is why I didn't explain that). This is why `t` is defined (rather than a parameter) in `Stack`, while `elt` is still (ultimately -- via `E`) a parameter.
 ListStack is a negative/unsatisfactory example, and illustrates why I want to do the renaming in the module type and not the module.

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio (cont) Because opaque (ie hidden) implementations of stack will only have, the operation `rd`, even if in the implementation we define a `push`.

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio What (I think) you are talking about with modules is not what I want. I want to describe abstract collections, along with some operations, and facts about them. eg, collections can be empty, and reading from an empty collection gives you nothing. Then I want to refine some of that abstraction (ie, I still want a module type) and say that stacks are a particular kind of collection, and I will have more to say about stacks, but I want all facts about collections apply to stacks. Also, I want that with stacks, wr & rd are called push & pop.

- Thanks

Comment: The Notation is not part of the module type. You can use a simple `Definition` here but it will add a field, not rename it.  I don’t think there is such a feature. Import is an « all or nothing » command afaik.

Comment: @C.E.Sally  Hm, I can understand the single lines, it's your pattern for reuse/extensibility that I cannot make (much) sense of.  Anyway, the bottom line (AFAIK) is just that you *cannot* "rename", at best you can provide new additional names: not in Coq where there is no way to hide what was included or imported (as even with opaque modules, at least their top-level names and signatures remain visible). -- I'll eventually make this into an answer unless something else comes up.

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio: On that we are in agreement. I at no point imagined that definition renamed anything. Sorry, that's my bad. My comment of "renaming" was left over crud from my actual development. I changed the comment to what I actually meant to say, in the question.

Comment: @PierreCourtieu That's what I was thinking too, but was wondering if there are known tips/tricks in the community.

Comment: Currently I can't compile your example. Before answering with some code I would like to understand what you want to achieve with `Elt`and `TypeElt`. In particular why having the type t in the argument module type `TypeElt`? If you want to make module type more precise you probably want to use something like the `Module Foo (E:Elt) <: Collection E with Definition t := list E.elt` instead.

Comment: @PierreCourtieu Fixed the compilation issue. Mm, re `Elt` vs `TypElt`; I'm partly just following a pattern I picked up from the standard library. Another justification is that the abstract type `t` of the data structure has to be parameterized somewhere. But once that's done in `Collection` (a to be included module type), we dispense with it in the "downstream" module types (that will include `Collection`) like Stack, since we will want to define `t` in implementations of stack, rather than leaving it a param. (I should have left it abstract in `Stack`; I've edited to reflect this)

Answer (score 0):

Notation are not part of the module type. So you need to make it a definition.
But if you put a definition in a module type then you must comply to it exactly in the module. So the definition of `push` must be exactly `Definition push := wr`.

```ml
  Module Type Stack (E: Elt).
    Definition elt := E.elt.
    Parameter t : Type.
    Include Collection.
    Definition push := wr. (* <- push must be exactly wr in any module of type Stack *)
  End Stack.

  Module ListStack (E: Elt) <: Stack E.
    Definition elt := E.elt.
    Definition t := list elt.
    (* In order to satisfy the Module Type Stack, we must provide an operation, wr and rd *)
    (* Definition push := @cons elt. Won't be accepted, cf above *)
    Definition wr := @cons elt. (* complying *)
    Definition rd (l:t) :=
    match l with
      nil => (None,l)
    | cons e l' => (Some e, l')
    end.
    Definition push := wr.
    Definition pop := rd.
  End ListStack.
```

If you want to avoid polluting `Stack` with `rd` and `wr` you have no choice but to define `Stack` independently from Collection (except a possible common sub-interface, but here you don't have one). Rule of thumb: use `Include Foo` only if you want to include the whole Foo. Otherwise split `Foo` into `WantedFoo` and `NotWantedFoo` and include only the former.

Below an adaptation of your code although I am still not sure why you want `TypElt` instead of only `Elt`.

```ml
Module Type TypElt.
  Parameter t elt : Type.
End TypElt.

Module Type Collection (Import T: TypElt).

  Parameter rd : t -> (option elt * t).
  Parameter wr : elt -> t -> t.

End Collection.


Module Type Elt .
  Parameter elt : Type.
End Elt.

Module Type Stack (E: Elt).

  Definition elt := E.elt.
  Parameter t: Type.

  (* Module Col := Collection E. *)

  Parameter pop : t -> (option elt * t).
  Parameter push : elt -> t -> t.

End Stack.

Module ListStack (E: Elt) <: Stack E.
  
  Definition elt := E.elt.
  Definition t := list elt.
  
  Definition push := @cons elt.
  Definition pop (l:t) :=
    match l with
      nil => (None,l)
    | cons e l' => (Some e, l')
    end.
End ListStack.

Module Type TypEltList <: TypElt.
  Parameter elt : Type.
  Definition t := list elt.
End TypEltList.

(* Collection with list *)
Module ListCollec (E: TypEltList) <: Collection E.
  (* Include E. *)
  Import E.                     (* Include pointless here *)
  Definition t := list elt.
  Definition wr := @cons elt.
  Definition rd (l:E.t) :=
    match l with
      nil => (None,l)
    | cons e l' => (Some e, l')
    end.
End ListCollec.

(* Function from one to the other *)
Module MakeStack (E:TypElt) (Col: Collection E) <: Stack E.
  Definition elt := E.elt.
  Definition t := E.t.
  Definition pop := Col.rd.
  Definition push := Col.wr. 
  (* Parameter peek : t -> option elt. *)
End MakeStack.
```